# How to use proxy in Minikube on Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, kubernetes, minikube

On an Ubuntu VM (running on Windows) I would like to install Minikube. My PC in running behind a corporate proxy. Using Proxifier I manage to access Internet and run Docker on Ubuntu. Unfortunately it looks like Minikube can't reach the internet...

```
minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
```

The ISO can't be downloaded but it runs into a TLS handshake timeout...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you could establish proxy using Proxifier.
So, you could possibly try something like this to force Minikube use Proxifier proxy as well

```
export NO_PROXY="$NO_PROXY,192.168.0.0/16" # set the no_proxy env variable in the current shell.
minikube start --docker-env "HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy:808" --docker-env "HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:808" --docker-env "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.0.0/16" # start minikube and pass the same no_proxy setting to docker
```

Specifying `192.168.0.0/16` as the range of ipaddresses that shouldn't go through the proxy as this is the range (I think) that minikube generate it's IP addresses in (and I'm certain that I don't have anything else in that range)

More details is available on Minikube’s Github issue https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2706

Answer (score 0):

[Minikube 1.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/v1.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#version-100---2019-03-27) (March 2019) now comes with [PR 3834](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/3834): "Automatically propagate proxy environment variables to docker env"

> Currently, our documentation recommends that users use:

```
minikube start \
--docker-env=HTTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY \
--docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTPS_PROXY \
 --docker-env NO_PROXY=$NO_PROXY
```

> This makes the setting of `--docker-env` automatic if the environment variables are set.

Implemented in [PR 3835](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/3835): "Plumb HTTP proxy configuration from host into VM environment"

> Detect system proxy configuration from environment, and plumb them into the docker env and `/etc/environment` within the VM by default.